# Do not how to fix the Problem in GC in spark cluster ,Can anybody explain how to deal with ParOldGen and PSYoungGen?

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection

Checked all the configuration provided shuffle `spark.default.parallelism,spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` 
 and all the required memory option like **executable-memory** and **driver memory** also. I have sufficient memory is around 64 GB, but do not know why it is coming up...

I want to know if it can be fixed by memory configuration. It executes all previous task but it fails on 31 tasks. The query size is big, it runs well for a small size query.

```
    logger.debug(String.format("Executing SQL %s", taskExec));
    Dataset<Row> dfTmp = null;
    dfTmp = sqlContext.sql(taskExec);


AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 107 
[PSYoungGen: 2917987K->2917987K(3547136K)] [ParOldGen: 8387375K- 
>8387375K(8388608K)] 11305363K->11305363K(11935744K), [Metaspace: 
 72368K->72368K(1114112K)], 0.4457447 secs] [Times: user=2.27 sys=0.00, 
 real=0.44 secs] 
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill 9085"...
282.474: [Full GC (Ergonomics) 282.535: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000665 secs]282.535: [WeakReference, 956 refs, 0.0001140 secs]282.535: [FinalReference, 1092 refs, 0.0000635 secs]282.535: [PhantomReference, 0 refs, 38 refs, 0.0000145 secs]282.536: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000145 secs]AdaptiveSizeStart: 283.597 collection: 108 
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size limits: desired_eden_size: 3086984786 old_eden_size: 3023044608 eden_limit: 3023044608 cur_eden: 2991587328 max_eden_size: 3023044608 avg_young_live: 2739392512
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: gc time limit gc_cost: 1.000000  GCTimeLimit: 98
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_eden_space_size: costs minor_time: 0.144870 major_cost: 0.975053 mutator_cost: 0.000000 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 11575527424 free_space: 5652873216 old_eden_size: 3023044608 desired_eden_size: 3023044608
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_old_gen_free_space limits: desired_promo_size: 3143082161 promo_limit: 2629828608 free_in_old_gen: 20183040 max_old_gen_size: 8589934592 avg_old_live: 8569751552
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_old_gen_free_space: gc time limit gc_cost: 1.000000  GCTimeLimit: 98
PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::compute_old_gen_free_space: costs minor_time: 0.144870 major_cost: 0.975053 mutator_cost: 0.000000 throughput_goal: 0.990000 live_space: 11577579520 free_space: 5652873216 old_promo_size: 2629828608 desired_promo_size: 2629828608
AdaptiveSizeStop: collection: 108 
[PSYoungGen: 2921472K->778705K(3547136K)] [ParOldGen: 8387375K->8386929K(8388608K)] 11308847K->9165634K(11935744K), [Metaspace: 72370K->72370K(1114112K)], 1.1228849 secs] [Times: user=8.59 sys=0.74, real=1.12 secs] 
10:51:46.868 [Executor task launch worker for task 9593] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 30.0 in stage 144.0 (TID 9593)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$$anonfun$sideBySide$1.apply(package.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$$anonfun$sideBySide$1.apply(package.scala:112)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$.sideBySide(package.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package$.sideBySide(package.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logDebug(Logging.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.logDebug(RuleExecutor.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$$anonfun$canonicalize$1.apply(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$$anonfun$canonicalize$1.apply(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:354)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.canonicalize(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.GenerateUnsafeProjection$.generate(GenerateUnsafeProjection.scala:362)
10:51:46.900 [SIGTERM handler] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
10:51:46.918 [Thread-2] INFO org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager - Shutdown hook called
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing **spark.memory.offHeap.size** memory

Comment: I think, It has no impact on heap memory usage.So I have not tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird kind of problem I was facing,Checked all the configuration details.
As I mentioned I have enough memory but it was giving the problem of GC out of memory.
So I was busy in looking at memory side configuration.

I read all the spark related articles.
[How to handle memory in Spark](https://www.pgs-soft.com/blog/spark-memory-management-part-1-push-it-to-the-limits/) .I went to similar problems in stack overflow,but no
one have same exact error in their problem.

This kind of error was found in scala version 2.13.x so I was suspicious that might me
mine TaskServiceImpl is throwing this exception but I was using 2.11.8.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
```

I tried to check this in cmd --->>scala>  "a".mkString(",").It was giving me correct output so I was sure this is not causing the problem,so **I tried to check hadoop version
so I tried to change it latest version of hadoop version 5.14.6 and it worked liked champ**.

I was using spark 2.11.8 with scala 2.11.8 and my hadoop version at CDH was 5.13.X.